# Print line if column 2 is greater than column 2 on the next line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with multiple lines that all have a date in the second column. I'm looking for a command that prints the whole line if the date is greater than the date on the next line.
When this is no longer the case I want it to stop, don't print anything else.

I'm a rookie so if you could explain your answer that would be great.

I'm trying to use awk (answer can be any command)

```
awk '$2 > ?nextline?$2 {print}' file
```

I couldn't find how to check next line or how to stop after the first time the greater than command isn't true.

Input:

```
Jan 20 text1  
Jan 15 text2  
Jan 15 text3  
Jan 3 text4  
Jan 27 text5  
Jan 17 text6  
(more lines...)
```

Wanted output:

```
Jan 20 text1  
Jan 15 text2  
Jan 15 text3  
Jan 3 text4
```

Comment: I am not getting how line `Jan 3 text4` is in your output, when this line's 3 is smaller than `Jan 27 text5`'s `27`? Could you please elaborate it more?

Comment: (column 2 dates) 20>15>3>27>17.  
27 is not smaller than 3. So I want everything from the first line to when the date goes from 3 to 27. When the following line has a larger date I don't want that output or anything after it.

Comment: Much like in life, in software it's a lot easier to do things based on what HAS happened than based on what WILL happen in  the future. So don't write requirements based on what the next line will contain, write them based on what a past line contained and you'll find it much easier to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `awk` version:

```
awk 'f && $2>f {exit} 1; {f=$2}' file
Jan 20 text1
Jan 15 text2
Jan 15 text3
Jan 3 text4
```

- `f && $2>f {exit}` Test if `f`is set and second field larger than `f`? Yes, exit the program.
- `1;` is always true, so print the line.
- `{f=$2}` set `f` to second field.

Cold even be shorten some more:

```
awk 'f&&$2>f{exit}f=$2' file
```

- `f=$2` By setting it as pattern it will be true and print at the same time as `f` is set to `$2`
- This version would skip print blank line between data if that exists, other not.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to reverse your requirement. Instead of printing out the current line if the next line does something, because sed, awk, etc., can't see the future, you need to stop printing if the current line does something compared to the previous line since awk and friends can see the past by storing it in a variable.

So a simple way, since you said language doesn't matter, is to do this:

```
perl -palE 'BEGIN {$h = 999} last if $F[1] > $h; $h = $F[1]' < file
```

What we are doing here is passing perl in `-p` "loop through input and print line at the end of the loop", `-a` "auto-split the line on spaces into the `@F` variable", `-l` "auto-handle line endings" (not strictly required here, but just a good habit *most of the time*), and `-E` "execute the code from the next parameter with the current version of perl specified" (`-e` would suffice here, but, again, habit). And the code we pass in starts off by setting `$h` (highest allowed at this point) to something out of range, I'm assuming no number will be 999+ since you say they're days of a month, using `last` to terminate the loop if the current day is higher than the highest allowed, and setting that high point to the current value if we get past the `if`. Perl now automatically prints out the current line and loops to the next line.

The key point is that we only look at the current line and track in a variable the relevant history so that we don't need to look into the future.